# A sharper bound than Chernoff for a sum of random variables

Tags: probability, random-variables

Let $X_i$ be i.i.d Bernoulli random variables with parameter $1/2$ i.e. a fair coin.

I am trying to find a good bound for
$$ \mathbb{P} \left( \sum_{i=1}^{1000} X_i \leq 599 \right) \ .$$
The moment generating function of $X_i$ is given by
$$\mathbb{E}(e^{\theta X_i}) =  \frac{e^\theta + 1}{2} $$
and by using the Chernoff bound
$$ \mathbb{P} \left( \sum_{i=1}^{\infty} X_i \leq 599 \right) \leq \inf_{t >0} \left(  e^{599t} \left( \frac{1 + e^{-t}}{2}\right)^{1000} \right) \ .$$
However, assuming my calculation was correct, WolframAlpha states that the function on the right is not minimizible.

Does anyone have any other techniques or hints for bounding these sorts of problems? I would much prefer a hint towards a suitable strategy, than an outright bound.

Comment: Correct your expression for mgf of $X_i$. The log won't be there.

Comment: The Chernov-Hoeffding bound is often easier to use when your $X_i$ variables are bounded, since you do not have to take the infimum over $t$. See here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hoeffding%27s_inequality

Comment: For example, the one-sided bound given in that link gives, for all $t>0$: $$P\left[\sum_{i=1}^n X_i \geq nE[X] + nt\right] \leq \exp\left(-\frac{2nt^2}{(b-a)^2}\right) $$ assuming $\{X_i\}$ are iid and satisfy $a \leq X_i \leq b$ for all $i$. In your case, $a=0, b=1$, $n=1000$, $E[X]=1/2$, $t=99/1000$.

Comment: One other typo-related thing I notice in your work:  The Chernov bound says htat $P[X\geq z] \leq E[e^{\theta X}]e^{-\theta z}$ for all $\theta \geq 0$. Applied to your problem it would be $$P\left[\sum_{i=1}^{1000} X_i \geq 599\right] \leq \left(\frac{1+e^{\theta }}{2}\right)^{1000} e^{-\theta 599}$$ and you can optimize over $\theta \geq 0$.  Somehow, you are using the change of variables $\theta =-t$, but still exploring over $t >0$ rather than $t<0$. You also seem to have an inequality $\leq$ when I would expect $\geq$.

Comment: Thank you for your comments Michael. I am using the bounds given by

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chernoff_bound

From the section "generic bounds" I am using the last bound.

Comment: Usually people apply Chernov bounds to calculate small quantities.  Since your inequality is flipped, you seem to be trying to bound a probability that is very close to 1.

Comment: If you try to use your inequality, I believe $e^{599t} \left(\frac{1+e^{-t}}{2}\right)^{1000}$ is nondecreasing in $t$ when $t\geq 0$. So its infimum is when $t=0$, which gives the "true but useless" bound $P\left[\sum_{i=1}^{1000}X_i \leq 599\right] \leq 1$.

Comment: Yes, I noticed that the bound was useless as well. This question is related to an exercise in finding the lower bound for a certain probability, but I have a feeling I have misinterpreted how "sharp" the bound was that was desired.

Comment: I do not understand your conclusions. I expected you to apply Chernov in the regime of interest (the version I give above) and then a lower bound is, for any $\theta \geq 0$: $$P\left[\sum_{i=1}^{1000} X_i \leq 599\right] = 1-P\left[\sum_{i=1}^{1000}X_i > 599\right] \geq 1 - \left(\frac{1+e^{\theta}}{2}\right)^{1000}e^{-\theta 599}$$ For example, if $\theta=0.1$ (which is likely not optimal) then $ \left(\frac{1+e^{\theta}}{2}\right)^{1000}e^{-\theta 599} \approx 0.000175$. So this gives a meaningful bound.

Comment: I am sorry if my conclusions were unclear. The actual question that I am trying to answer : is to find a reasonable lower and upper bound for the probability $\mathbb{P} \left( \sum_{i=1}^{1000} X_i > 599 \right)$. I already have an sharp upper bound for the probability, so next I was interested in a lower bound, and I thought to find that lower bound my maximizing $\mathbb{P} \left(\sum_{i=1}^{1000} X_i  \leq 599 \right)$. The problem of course is that the probability is extremely close to $0$ so with my current knowledge of probabiltiy theory, a good bound does not seem easy to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you can use CLT for Normal approximation to Binomial. $1000$ is a pretty large number so you can say that your probability is "like" a normal cdf with specified parameters.

In other words, denoting $S_n=\sum_{i=1}^n X_i$ we have by CLT that $\dfrac{S_n-\dfrac{n}{2}}{\sqrt{\dfrac{n}{4}}}\to \mathcal N(0,1)$ weakly, as $n\to\infty$.

Thus $P[S_n\leq t]\sim \Phi\left(\dfrac{t-\dfrac{n}{2}}{\sqrt{\dfrac{n}{4}}}\right)$ for large enough $n$. Your $n=1000,t=599$. Plug them in.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I am looking for a quantitative bound. In addition we have not yet covered the CLT rigorously so I am assuming that its use is prohibited.